# List down only entities which share the same field value as another

Tags: views, entities, 9

I'd like to have a View of entities (e.g. nodes) that only "show duplicates", i.e. show entities that have a specific field having a value that's also used by two or more entities. To put it simply, only include items that cause a specific field to show the same value more than once in the table.

In the following example, in a view of nodes, only nodes 1, 2, 3, and 5 should be included because they share the same `field_text` values with another node.

```
title   field_text
Node 1  foo        <- include because foo
Node 2  bar        <- include because bar
Node 3  bar        <- include because bar
Node 4  baz
Node 5  foo        <- include because foo
Node 6  qux
```

Additional constraints are:

- The field must be text. It's a keyed-in alphanumeric code from an external system.
- The field cannot be an entity reference of any kind.
- This setup may be used for exports (e.g. CSVs) or endpoints (e.g. JSON) so template-level sorcery is non-starter.

Is this possible out of the box? Is there an existing module that enables this?